# Bash execute multiple command stored in variable without eval

Tags: bash, shell, eval

I have a script `wrapper.sh` it takes a string as an argument.

wrapper.sh

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
node ./index.js $1
```

Now if I pass argument as `hello` it runs fine but if I pass `hello&pwd` then it passes full string as an argument to the nodejs file instead of just passing hello in nodejs and running pwd separately.

Example

```sh
./wrapper.sh "hello"
# nodejs gets argument hello : Expected


./wrapper.sh "hello&pwd"
# nodejs gets argument hello&pwd : Not Expected
# Requied only hello in nodejs while pwd running separately
```

I have tried a lot of solutions online but none seem to work except `eval` and `bash -c` which I don't want to use because the script doesn't wait for these commands to finish.

#### Edit

`wrapper.sh` is executed by a third party software and the content of the script is dynamically configured by the user so there's nothing much in my hand. Job of my module is to just setup the script properly that it is executed by the third party software.

Comment: The shell expands parameters (and variables and ...) *after* parsing most command syntax (like `&`), so putting shell syntax in parameters doesn't do anything useful unless you use something like `eval` or `bash -c` to force a second parsing pass (warning: a second parsing pass will parse *everything* again, not just the parts you want/expect to be re-parsed, and so can cause weird and dangerous bugs). But this sounds like it may be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info) -- what are you actually trying to accomplish with this, and might there be a better approach?

Comment: `./wrapper.sh hello && pwd`?

Comment: @Shawn The script is executed by some other third party so I can't control how the argument is passed.

Comment: @GordonDavisson the content of the wrapper script is dynamically configured by the user and the wrapper script is executed by a third party system so I am just stuck in this senario

Comment: @ShubhamKumar But why are you trying to pass it something that's partly argument(s) to nodejs, and partly shell syntax/commands? This seems like a messy kluge to work around a system that wasn't designed to do what you want it to do.

Comment: @GordonDavisson The reason being is my module is a cross platform module thus in windows batch file, & breaks the command in two. I want to give uniformity to my users.

Comment: I also tried to escape the incoming argument in batch file for windows but didn't got a well documented way to do it.

Comment: @ShubhamKumar Bash does not support cmd.exe syntax. These are two different languages, and e.g. `&` means a different thing in each. `eval` and `bash -c` don't work because they evaluate as a bash script and not as a cmd.exe script. If you want users to be able to use cmd.exe syntax with your bash script, you need to implement this yourself.

Comment: I don't want to implement cmd in bash. By uniformity I mean `$var` shouldn't mean `"$var"` in windows.

Comment: @ShubhamKumar You're not going to be able to get uniformity between bash and DOS batch, and it's a mistake to even try. For instance, in batch `cmd1 & cmd2` means run `cmd1` and then `cmd2`, but in bash it means start `cmd1` in the background and run `cmd2` *at the same time*. The bash equivalent of batch's `&` is `;`, but in batch a semicolon is an argument delimiter. So even if you solve the quoting mismatch, pretty much everything else will be different too. Just don't try to get bash to behave like batch or vice versa, it's fundamentally not going to work.